# Use higher API level in android with an external library

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, material-design

Would it be possible to import an external library (.jar file) in an android project containing the features of API level 21, and then use them in my application with a minimum sdk version set to say like 17?
I'm *really* into Matierial Design but as Google states, "*To use material design in your Android apps, follow the guidelines defined in the material design specification and use the new components and functionality available in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above.*", so is there no way around this? Is there a way to implement Material Design and those transitions on a lower API level android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use limited features from material design in pre-lollipop versions. No Path Animations and such. Check out this link to see which features can be backported.

```
    http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html
```

Although now it is appcompat-v22 which is the latest SDK released by Google.